# my footer doesn't stay at the bottom of the site when I zoom out the site

Tags: javascript, html, css

Pls help me, I am making a site and my footer isn't staying at the bottom, when I zoom out the site. I'm a beginner so the code can be a little messy.

[as you can see, the footer doesn't stay at the bottom, I have searched here for people with a similar problem with the code and I found some. And I tried some of the solutions, but none of them worked for me.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GE9nm.jpg)

I think it doesn't work because there's something else wrong with my css, but I just cant figure it out.

```css
html{
box-sizing:border-box;
-ms-text-size-adjust:100%;
-webkit-text-size-adjust:100%;
}

*,*:before,*:after{
    box-sizing:inherit
}

body{
    margin: 0;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    background-color: #f6f6f6;
}

ul {
        padding: 4px 8px;
        float: right;
}

a.nav-button {
    padding: 8px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: black;
    letter-spacing: 4px;
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    font-family: Verdana,sans-serif;
    font-size: 15px;
    line-height: 1.5;
}

a.nav-button:hover {
    background-color: #cccccc;
}

img.logo{
    padding-top: 14px;
    height: 50px;
    float:left;
}

div.menu{
    position:fixed;
    width:100%;
    z-index:1;
    background-color: #ffffff;
}

div.front_img{
    padding-top:500;
    vertical-align: middle;
    display:inline-block;
    max-width:100%;
    width: 100%;
    max-height: 60%;
    position: relative;
    background-image: url(../images/front_image.jpg);
    background-size: cover;
    left:50%;
    top:0;
    transform:translate(-50%,0%);
    -ms-transform:translate(-50%,0%);
}

div.webpage {
    max-width:980px;
    margin:auto;
}

div.container {
    padding:0.01em 16px;
    padding-top:32px;
    padding-bottom: 32px;
    max-width: 100%;
    position: relative;
    left:50%;
    top:0;
    transform:translate(-50%,0%);
    -ms-transform:translate(-50%,0%);
    background-color: #f6f6f6;
}

div.article {
    padding:0.01em 16px;
    padding-top:32px;
    padding-bottom: 32px;
    max-width: 100%;
    position: relative;
    left:50%;
    top:0;
    transform:translate(-50%,0%);
    -ms-transform:translate(-50%,0%);
    background-color: #f6f6f6;
}

div.h3-container {
   border-bottom:1px solid #ccc;
   width:100%;
}

h3 {
    font-size: 24px;
    font-family: "Segoe UI",Arial,sans-serif;
    font-weight: 400;
    margin: 10px 0;
}

p {
    font-family: Verdana,sans-serif;
    font-size: 15px;
    line-height: 1.5;
    display: block;
    -webkit-margin-before: 1em;
    -webkit-margin-after: 1em;
    -webkit-margin-start: 0px;
    -webkit-margin-end: 0px;
}

div.footer {
   position: relative;
   padding-top: 6;
   padding-bottom: 6;
   padding-right: 8;
   width: 100%;
   text-align: right;
   background-color: black;   
   color: goldenrod;
}

div.footer, a{
    color: goldenrod;
}

div.footer-container {
    position: relative;
    padding:0.01em 16px;
    padding-top:32px;
    padding-bottom: 32px;
    max-width: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: black;
    color:goldenrod;
    left:50%;
    top:0;
    transform:translate(-50%,0%);
    -ms-transform:translate(-50%,0%);
    border-bottom:1px solid goldenrod;
}

div.footer-background{
    background-color: black;
    overflow: hidden;
}
 
div.leverancier-wrap {
    padding-left: 22;
    background-color: white;
}

div.footer-content {
    // tried position:fixed; here but didnt work :c 
}
    
HTML
```

```html
<div class="footer-content">
    <div class="container" style="max-width:1564px">
        <div class="h3-container" id="intoduction">
             <h3 class="Welcome-title"><img src="images/location_icon.png" height="30" length="20" hspace="20"/>Installatietechniek Haaglanden bevindt zich hier.</h3>
        </div> 
    </div>
    <style>
     #map {
       width: 100%;
       height: 400px;
       background-color: grey;
       border-bottom: 5pt solid black;
     }
    </style>
    <div id="map"></div>
        <script>
          function initMap() {
            var uluru = {lat: 52.0442081, lng: 4.3370828};
            var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
              zoom: 17,
              center: uluru
            });
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
              position: uluru,
              map: map
            });
          }
        </script>
        <script async defer
        src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=[aint getting mah map]&callback=initMap">
        </script>

    <div class="leverancier-wrap">
      <img class="leveranciers" src="http://www.installatietechniekhaaglanden.nl/images/slide1.jpg"  height="30" width="300">
      <img class="leveranciers" src="http://www.installatietechniekhaaglanden.nl/images/slide2.jpg"  height="30" width="300">
      <img class="leveranciers" src="http://www.installatietechniekhaaglanden.nl/images/slide3.jpg"  height="30" width="300">
      <img class="leveranciers" src="http://www.installatietechniekhaaglanden.nl/images/slide4.jpg"  height="30" width="300">
    </div>
        <div class="footer-background">
            <div class="footer-container" style="max-width:1564px">
                <div class="footer-text">
                    <h3>Contactgegevens</h3>
                    <p>Installatietechniek Haaglanden<span style="display:inline-block; width: 280px;"><img src="images/telphone-icon.png" height="16" length="8" hspace="259"/></span>070 7620180</p>
                    <p>Burgemeester Elsenlaan 321<span style="display:inline-block; width: 297px;"><img src="images/mail-icon.png" height="16" length="8" hspace="276"/></span>info@installatietechniekhaaglanden.nl</p>
                    <p>2282 MZ Rijswijk<a href="https://www.facebook.com/installatietechniekhaaglanden/"><img src="images/facebook-icon.png" height="16" length="8" hspace="362"/></a></p> 
                </div>     
            </div>
        </div>
    <div class="footer">
        <p>Copyright © installatietechniekhaaglanden.nl. Designed by <a href="">ajeeth</a></p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

## Negative margin method

Use a negative bottom margin like this. Keep the `.push` div empty.

*HTML*

```html
<body>
  <div class="wrapper">

      ...content...

    <div class="push"></div>
  </div>
  <footer class="footer">All rights reserved</footer>
</body>
```

*CSS*

```css
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}
.wrapper {
  min-height: 100%;

  /* Equal to height of footer */
  /* But also accounting for potential margin-bottom of last child */
  margin-bottom: -50px;
}
.footer,
.push {
  height: 50px;
}
```

Full demo: [codepen.io](https://codepen.io/chriscoyier/pen/VjZmGj)

## Other methods

You can also use `negative top margins`, `calc()`, `flexbox`, and `grid` to achieve the same effect in a better way.

Original source: [This and 4 other ways originates from css-tricks.com](https://css-tricks.com/couple-takes-sticky-footer/)

Answer (score -1):

Give `position: fixed;` and to fix it at the bottom even if the content is little like the below demo

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

div.footer-content {
  background: red;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

HTML
```

```html
<div class="footer-content">
  this is the footer
</div>
```

Comment: I did what you said, but now the footer is over the content of my page.

Answer (score -1):

You mean a Sticky Footer?
Change the CSS in

```
    .footer-content { position: absolute; bottom: 0; width: 100%; }
```

Comment: Öhm okey... maybe another mistake? The Footer is the Black block with the Google Maps? That works with me.

Comment: The Footer is outside from the Content?

Comment: yes it is outside from the content. I just included it.

Comment: </div>
    <?php
    include 'includes/footer.php';
    ?>
    </body>
</html> '

Comment: I think it is a little HTML Error hm.... Can you check all closed Tags?

Comment: The div.footer is position:relative; Where´s the <footer> Tag? Its the parent Tag?

Comment: i didnt use a footer tag and the div.footer is relative because the text will float to the left, that why i did it. but I deleted relative to check if that was the problem and it wasn't.

Comment: Have you tried position: fixed; width: 100%; bottom: 0px; ?